# Composite Primary Key in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, template-haskell

I am fairly new to Haskell and have been experimenting with yesod for about a week now. I have been trying to connect to an existing database that has a composite primary key in sqlite. I managed to get the code to work with `Database.Persist.Sqlite` as a standalone application.

Here is the code that works as a standalone application using `persistent-sqlite`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class  (liftIO)
import           Database.Persist
import           Database.Persist.Sqlite
import           Database.Persist.TH
import           System.Environment
import           Data.Text (Text,pack)
import           Data.Time (UTCTime)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
    Movie
    title Text maxlen=20
    year Int maxlen=11
    genre Text Maybe maxlen=128
    mpaa Text Maybe maxlen=16
    director Text Maybe maxlen=128
    actors Text Maybe maxlen=512
    description Text Maybe maxlen=512
    path Text Maybe maxlen=128
    codec Text Maybe maxlen=32
    length Int Maybe maxlen=11
    poster Text Maybe maxlen=128
    added UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    Primary title year
    deriving Show
|]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (path:args) <- getArgs
  movies <- runSqlite (pack path) $ do
    runMigration migrateAll
    selectList [] [Desc MovieTitle]

  mapM_ print movies
```

This is sort of a contrived example, but it illustrates my point. I would like to have a composite primary key that consists of `title` and `year`. Everything compiles fine and the table is created with the schema that I need. When I try to use the `Movie` type as defined above in my yesod application with `persistent-sqlite`, I get the following compile-time error

```
Foundation.hs:35:1:
    No instance for (PathPiece MovieId)
      arising from a use of ‘toPathPiece’
    In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(toPathPiece dyn_apvA)’
    In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely
      ‘((toPathPiece dyn_apvA) : [])’
    In the expression:
      ((Data.Text.pack "entry") : ((toPathPiece dyn_apvA) : []))

Foundation.hs:35:1:
    No instance for (PathPiece MovieId)
      arising from a use of ‘fromPathPiece’
    In the expression: fromPathPiece
    In the pattern: fromPathPiece -> Just dyn_apwt
    In the pattern: (:) (fromPathPiece -> Just dyn_apwt) []
```

I am stuck at this point and unable to continue on my own. I have tried searching, but I am only able to find a working example of composite primary keys without the use of yesod. I have a feeling that it should be possible to do since the composite primary key using only `persistent-sqlite` works.

Here is how the `Movie` type is defined in `config/models`

```
Movie
    title Text maxlen=20
    year Int maxlen=11
    genre Text Maybe maxlen=128
    mpaa Text Maybe maxlen=16
    director Text Maybe maxlen=128
    actors Text Maybe maxlen=512
    description Text Maybe maxlen=512
    path Text Maybe maxlen=128
    codec Text Maybe maxlen=32
    length Int Maybe maxlen=11
    poster Text Maybe maxlen=128
    added UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    Primary title year
    deriving
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't actually used the composite primary key feature myself, but this error makes sense to me. There's not obvious serialization to `Text` for arbitrary composite keys, and so persistent doesn't generate it for you. If you'd like to use a `MovieId` inside your URLs, you'll need to manually define the `PathPiece` instance, which is just a pair of functions for converting to and from `Text`.